# Numpy Array into Tensor

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have SEED-IV dataset and I want it to use for emotion recognition using MLP. I converted the preprocessed data into separate npy arrays and saved all those arrays into a single file. After loading the data I wanted to convert x and y labels into tensors and then make x and y training datasets to use to train the model. The problem is, all of my arrays are in different shapes, and therefore I'm not able to convert them into tensors. How do I overcome this issue? Please Help. Thank You!

I have tried these two methods

```
reshaped_arrays = {}
for key in loaded_data.keys():
    # Skip the 'labels' array
    if key == 'labels':
        continue
    # Reshape the array to the desired shape
    reshaped_array = loaded_data[key].reshape(new_shape)
    # Store the reshaped array in the dictionary
    reshaped_arrays[key] = reshaped_array

# Extract x and y data
x = np.concatenate(list(reshaped_arrays.values()), axis=0)
y = loaded_data['labels']

x_data_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(x, dtype=tf.float32)
y_data_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=tf.float32)

# Split the data into training and test sets
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_data_tensor, y_data_tensor, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

```
 for arr_name in loaded_data:
     arr = loaded_data[arr_name]
     x_data.append(arr[:-1])
     y_data.append(arr[-1])

 #Convert the lists to numpy arrays
 x_data = np.array(x_data)
 y_data = np.array(y_data)
 x_data_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(x, dtype=tf.float32)
 y_data_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=tf.float32)

# Split the data into training and test sets
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_data_tensor, y_data_tensor, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

Answer (score 0):

After reshaping the array format, you can reshape the tensor format what you want with `torch.Tensor.reshape`, If using `torch` is not problem for your environment.

**Reference**

- https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.reshape.html